# Modify VBScript to Send Email to User Defined Address

Tags: vbscript

I found a rather useful VBScript which adds a Send To context menu item, allowing the use to send multiple documents as an attachment to an Outlook mail template. I currently use a similar script to generate an email based on some user input and wanted to know how to update this script to include a field for the To field or send to address.

Ultimately, I'd like to get the send to address from the user, any selected attachments, the subject, the body, and automatically send the email, without forcing the user to click the send button in Outlook. But for now, I'd be happy just getting and inserting the Send To address and adding the selected files as attachments.

Forgive me, I've little to no knowledge of VBScript and I'm not even sure if what I want to do is possible. If you have any suggestions, please feel free to share!

Here is the VBScript:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strSendTo = WshShell.SpecialFolders("SendTo") & "\"
strShortcutFileName = strSendTo & "\" & "Mail Recipient (as Path)" & ".lnk"
strMsg = "Completed!" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "SendLinkToMail.vbs - © 2010 Ramesh Srinivasan" & Chr(10) & "Visit us at http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/"
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
If WScript.Arguments.Count >  0 Then

    For I = 0 to objArgs.Count - 1
        If Left(WScript.Arguments.Item(I), 2) = "\\" Then
            strLinks =  strLinks & "%0A" & "%3C" & Replace(WScript.Arguments.Item(I)," ", "%20") & "%3E"
        Else
            strLinks =  strLinks & "%0A" & "%3C" & "file:///" & Replace(WScript.Arguments.Item(I)," ", "%20") & "%3E" & "%0A"
        End If      
    Next

    'Customize the Recipient Email and Subject here
    strRecipientEMail = ""
    strMailSubject = "File Paths"

    strMailSubject = Replace(strMailSubject," ","%20")
    On Error Resume Next

    WshShell.run "mailto:" & strRecipientEMail & "?Subject=" & strMailSubject & "&body=" & strLinks

    If Err <> 0 Then
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case 70
                If MsgBox ("Cannot send to mail as the parameters are too long. Do you want to output the file paths to a text file instead?",vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                    strLinks =  Replace(strLinks,"%20"," ")
                    strLinks =  Replace(strLinks,"%0A",vbCrLf)
                    txtFilePaths= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%") & "\FilePaths.txt"
                    Set b = objFSO.CreateTextFile (txtFilePaths,true)
                    b.WriteLine strLinks
                    b.close
                    WshShell.run "notepad.exe " & txtFilePaths
                End If

            Case Else
                MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " occurred."

        End Select
    End If
    On Error Goto 0 
Else
    rtn= Trim(UCase(InputBox ("Type INSTALL to add the MAIL RECIPIENT (as Path) to the Send To menu, or type UNINSTALL if you wish to remove the option.",  "Configuring SendLinkToMail.vbs...", "INSTALL")))
    If rtn = "INSTALL" Then RunInstall
    If rtn = "UNINSTALL" Then RunUninstall
End If

Sub RunInstall
    Set oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strShortcutFileName)
    oShellLink.TargetPath = WScript.ScriptFullName
    oShellLink.IconLocation = "sendmail.dll,-2001"
    oShellLink.Save
    MsgBox strMsg, vbokonly,"Installed"
End Sub

Sub RunUninstall
    if objFSO.fileexists(strShortcutFileName) then objFSO.deletefile(strShortcutFileName)
    MsgBox strMsg, vbokonly,"Uninstalled"
End Sub
```

Here is the current script (batch):

```
Title GFI Fax Maker
Echo off
cls
:Start
Set Name=_
Set SurName=_
Set Company=_
Set Department=_

Set /P Name=Type the Recipient's First name: 
Set /P SurName=Type the Recipient's Last name: 
Set /P Company=Type the Recipient's Company name: 
:: Set /P Department=Type the Recipient's Department name: 
Set /P Number=Type the Recipient's Fax Number: 

cls
:Verify
Echo ________________
Echo Recipient's First Name: %Name%
Echo Recipient's Last Name: %SurName%
Echo Recipient's Company Name: %Company%
:: Echo Recipient's Department Name: %Department%
Echo Recipient's Fax Number: %Number%
Set /P Correct=Is this correct? 
If %Correct%==n GOTO Start
If %Correct%==N GOTO Start

if %Number:~0,2%==91 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.note /m %Name%.%Company%.%SurName%.%Department%.%Number%@hspsfax.com
if %Number:~0,2%==91 GOTO END

if %Number:~0,1%==1 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.note /m %Name%.%Company%.%SurName%.%Department%.9%Number%@hspsfax.com
if %Number:~0,1%==1 GOTO End

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.note /m %Name: =%.%Company: =_%.%SurName: =%.%Department: =_%.91%Number: =%@hspsfax.com

:End
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `InputBox` where the user to enter recipient mail address.

```
strRecipientEMail = InputBox("Enter recipient address", "SendLinkToMail", "...")
```

Comment: You should also add some input sanitizing to make sure that users can only enter e-mail addresses and not arbitrary strings.

Comment: Is it possible to modify this to append the files as attachments rather than links in the body?

Comment: @Simpleton - I think you can by appending "&attachment=file:///..." to your "mailto:" command.

Comment: I tried modifying it like so:

    WshShell.run "mailto:" & strRecipientEMail & "?Subject=" & strMailSubject & "&body=" & strLinks & "&attachment=C:\Link\to\my\file.txt" 

But it failed!

Comment: @Simpleton - Did you try with "&attachment=file:///C:\Link\to\my\file.txt"? Also be sure you replaced intervals (" ") in the path (if any) with "%20"